# PyGithub: How to move inside a git branch and list all the content that present in sub folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, github, pygithub

```
from github import Github

access_token = "MYACCESS_TOKEN"
g=Github(access_token, retry=20)

repo = g.get_repo("pygit/git")
print(repo.name)

branches = repo.get_branches()
for branch in branches:
    print(branch.name)


for file in repo.get_contents(""):
    print(file.name)
```

Here I can list the branches. [I have 5 branches] I can list all the branches and I am able to view the content present in the root level of the repository.

But I am not able to select particular branch. where my data is present inside a subfolder of particular branch.

Expecting:

1. List all branches in a repository [Done]
2. Move inside a particular branch.
3. List all the contents inside a branch including directories.
4. Move inside a directory.
5. List all the content present in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this example](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Repository.html#get-all-of-the-contents-of-the-repository-recursively) in the PyGithub docs to list contents in a repository. The [`get_contents`](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Repository.html#github.Repository.Repository.get_contents) method accepts an optional `ref` parameter to which you can pass a branch's name.

For example:

```
for branch in branches:
  contents = repo.get_contents("", ref=branch.name)
  while contents:
    file_content = contents.pop(0)
    if file_content.type == "dir":
      contents.extend(repo.get_contents(file_content.path, ref=branch.name))
    else:
      print(file_content)
```